# Toggle (or slide) out specific div on click and hide others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've been browsing all day trying to find and answer to my problem. I'm stumped now and been running into walls. There are a lot of other topics about showing divs in an accordion-style (bootstrap) but my markup is a lot different than the examples I'm seeing. The way my page is setup is with 3 columns next to each other, then the divs  that will appear(on the next row), coming up beneath these columns. I keep running into a lot of parent, child, and next scripts.

[snapshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0P3g.jpg) 
[Better description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz95b.png)

My first question is: is this even possible with my markup? I've tried using the `.accordion-group` class and data-parent technique but that accomplishes nothing. The other divs that were opened beforehand still persist and must be closed manually.

Secondly, how can I accomplish this?

My markup is as follows:

```
<section class="no-padding" id="products">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row no-gutter">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a class="portfolio-box" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#drums1">
                    <img src="" alt="img-1" class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-category text-faded">Category<br>Click for details</div>
                            <div class="project-name">Rock Drums</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a class="portfolio-box" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#drums3">
                    <img src="" alt="img-3" class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                Category
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-name">Hip-Hop Drums<br></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-descriptions collapse" id="drums1">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">Buy and description here</div>
              <div class="col-md-6"><iframe width="854" height="480" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-descriptions collapse" id="drums2">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">Buy and description here</div>
              <div class="col-md-6"><iframe width="854" height="480" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-descriptions collapse" id="drums3">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6"><iframe width="854" height="480" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
              <div class="col-md-6">Buy and description here</div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

The `.product-descriptions` classes just set the `display:none`.

Edit: The second image is a better description. The red crosses are "links" `.portfolio-box` that will open up the div(green box - `.product-descriptions`). Each red box has its own corresponding div. The green box is hidden until shown by clicking on the red boxes. I want the corresponding green box to change when a different red box is clicked.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :) Nicely formatted question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a example for a simple bootstrap accordion: When you click on one, it closes the others. There are 3 panels. First panel is open by default using the class "in".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Accordion</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. What is HTML?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. What is Bootstrap?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Bootstrap is a powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">3. What is CSS?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. CSS allows you to specify various style properties for a given HTML element such as colors, backgrounds, fonts etc. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yea, I read over their docs extensively. My markup is much different. The divs that will be appearing are not siblings of the 'data-toggle's

Comment: Based on what i understood, you want panels of your accordion to appear in 3 different columns. For them to act as in a group you will need to enclose them in a div with class of panel-group. But by default an accordion has them stacked one below the other. You could probably achieve this by re-styling the panels. Not sure if you can achieve this directly by using bootstrap predefined classes.

Comment: Yea, I think I've exhausted the using bootstrap's pre-defined classes. I just left them on there cause it emulates some of the functionality I'd like. I've also updated my original post so it's easier to understand.